# Eliminar excepto cuando haya una palabra clave

Tags: regex, r

Intento eliminar todos los números del texto, excepto si están precedidos por la palabra `hospital`.

Tengo:

```
data<-c("3l hospital 11 esta a la vu3lt4")

data<- gsub("\\b(?![hospital])\\s[0-9]|[0-9]", "",  data, perl = T)
```

y mi resultado es:

```
 "l hospital esta a la vult"
```

Resultado esperado:

```
 "l hospital 11 esta a la vult"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La solución consiste en hacer coincidir y capturar en un grupo cualquier excepción, o coincidir sin capturar lo que se quiere eliminar:

```
(excepción 1|excepción 2|etc.)|lo que quiero eliminar
```

reemplazando por lo que se haya capturado: `\1`.

---

Código:

```
data <- c("3l hospital 11 esta a la vu3lt4")

data <- gsub("(hospital\\s+\\d+)|\\d+", "\\1",  data, perl = T)
```

Resultado:

```
[1] "l hospital 11 esta a la vult"
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/H4vyYl

---

Alternativamente, si se prefiere usar los [verbos de control](http://www.rexegg.com/backtracking-control-verbs.html) `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)`:

```
excepción(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|lo que quiero eliminar
```

Código:

```
data <- c("3l hospital 11 esta a la vu3lt4")
data <- gsub("hospital\\s+\\d+(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\\d+", "",  data, perl = T)
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/iXyTj7